# Splitting strings in nested loops and iterating through results bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, split

I have the following snippet in a script to generate a yaml file(ansible inventory) based on a single argument passed to the script. I have a feeling there is something fairly trivial wrong with my code but cannot identify what. The loop only extracts the first item from each array.

snippet:

```bash
IFS=',' read -a hostsByType <<< "$1" # arg in format type1@ip1:ip2:,type2@ip3:,
for val in "$hostsByType";do
    echo "$val" >> /logs/ansible-debug.log
    if [[ "$val" != "" ]];then
        IFS='@' read -a data <<< "$val"
        echo "    ${data[0]}:" >> inventory.yml
        IFS=':' read -a hosts <<< "${data[1]}"
        c=1
        for host in "$hosts";do
            echo "$host" >> /logs/ansible-debug.log
            if [[ "$host" != "" ]];then
              echo "      host${c}: $host" >> inventory.yml
              c=$(($c + 1))
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

ansible-debug.log:

```
type1@ip1:ip2:
ip1
```

inventory.yml:

```yaml
...
    type1:
      host1: ip1
...
```

Comment: In bash, `"$hostsByType"` only gets the first element of the array (and the same for `"$hosts"`). You need `for val in "${hostsByType[@]}"`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ah. I was treating an array as a multiline string. You are correct! Would you like to provide an answer for me to accept?

Comment: Probably better to mark it as a duplicate (for stackoverflow purposes it's best to funnel variants of a problem to a single comprehensive collection of answers). Although given how easy it is to make this mistake, I had a surprisingly hard time finding a good Q&A covering it...